# How to Load external .class file in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, reflection

I am trying to load and get some information of class in Java. In the following code `[file, file2]` are in the same eclipse project and `[file3]` is in the android studio project. But the following line get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

```
Class c3 = loader.loadClass("edu.test.activity.GPSActivity");
```

Does java support to load class that does not exist in the current project ? If possible how can I get?

```
private void test() {
    File file = new File("C:/jworkspace/all_java/bin/edu/test/annotate/");
    File file2 = new File("C:/jworkspace/all_java/bin/edu/test/collections/");
    File file3 = new File("C:/android/workspace/AllTest/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/edu/test/activity/");
    try {
        URLClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader
                .newInstance(new URL[] { file.toURI().toURL(), file2.toURI().toURL(), file3.toURI().toURL() });
        Class c = loader.loadClass("edu.test.annotate.Account");
        Class c2 = loader.loadClass("edu.test.collections.StackTest");
        Class c3 = loader.loadClass("edu.test.activity.GPSActivity");
        System.out.println(c.getName());
        System.out.println(c2.getName());
        System.out.println(c3.getName());
        loader.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `"C:/jworkspace/all_java/bin"` instead of `"C:/jworkspace/all_java/bin/edu/test/annotate/"` etc. work?

Comment: @howlger Yes, "C:/jworkspace/all_java/bin" work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the `URLClassLoader` with the classes/`bin` root directories, without the package subdirectories:

```
File file = new File("C:/jworkspace/all_java/bin");
File file2 = new File("C:/jworkspace/all_java/bin");
File file3 = new File("C:/android/workspace/AllTest/app/build/intermediates/classes");
```

Note, `URLClassLoader` is used for **dynamically loading** of classes whose location is not known before running the application. In your case, adding these directories to the Java build path might do the trick:

1. In ***Project > Properties: Java Build Path***, tab ***Libraries*** click ***Add External Class Folder...***
2. **Choose the directory** and click ***OK***
3. Repeat step 1. and 2. for the other two directories

In the Java code, only the corresponding import statement is then required, e. g. `import edu.test.annotate.Account;`.

Comment: The error change to "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/location/LocationListener". I am using LocationListener interface in that class. How to overcome this one? How to make to get proper information of that class?

Comment: Add the JAR that contains `android.location.LocationListener` to the Java Build Path of the project or add the directory that contains the `android/location/LocationListener.class` to your `URLClassLoader`.

Answer (score 1):

> Does java support to load class that does not exist in the current project ? If possible how can I get?

Java does not have a concept for "current project", nor does it have any idea of projects. Projects exist in Eclipse only, not in Java.

To make your thing work, I would introduce a compile-time dependency in your current project level: Right-mouse click on it in Eclipse, then choose "Properties", then "Java Build Path"  then "Libraries", then "Add class Folder", where you would add the class folder of your andorid project and click "Apply" and "OK".